# When does hive URL-encode partition key names?

Tags: hive

I have tried inserting partitions like 'a:b' into Hive (0.13), and sometimes it ends up with "a%3Ab".  Is that something Hive does (if so, when), or is there some other layer along the way?

[This issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3679) would indicate that Hive maintainers have seen this before.